# Spring MVC - Spring Security : How to have two different "types" of users, to which I will display different content in the jsp pages

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I would like to have two types of users, let's say Teacher and Student.

A lot of the content of the app will be shown to both types of users, but "Teacher" users will see some stuff that "Student" users won't be able to see.

The approach I was thinking to take was to have a ROLE_Teacher and a ROLE_Student instead of a ROLE_User, but I am not sure that would be the best practice, plus, I would have to modify every JSP to make the tests when I want to display specific content.

Did someone try to solve the same kind of problem before? Does Spring contains some mechanism to accomplish this already?

Answer (score 2):

I think defining different roles is pretty much the standard way to solve the problem. Spring Security provides support to constrain the content generated by JSPs based on the roles of the currently authenticated user. (The related documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/taglibs.html) And, of course you will have to modify every JSP to serve only the content which is appropriate to the user's role. I don't think there is some kind of magic that would do that job for you. :)